# How to determine the type of a querset in django

Tags: django

How can I check to know the 'TYPE' of my database queryset. I want to use an 'IF' statement to do something when a certain condition is met but I don't know how to go about it.

```
def tot_query(request):
    fb = Fblink.objects.all()
    tw = Twlink.objects.all()
    yt = Ytlink.objects.all()
    th = Thlink.objects.all()
    ig = Iglink.objects.all()
    sc = Sclink.objects.all()
    tk = Tklink.objects.all()

    query = chain(fb, tw, yt, th, ig, sc, tk)

    print(type(list(query)[0]))

    if type(list(query)[0]) == 'src.link.models.Fblink':
        print("This is a facebook link")
```

The first print statement prints the following <class 'src.link.models.Fblink'>
and  the second one prints nothing.

Comment: Your `query` is *not* a `QuerySet`, that is a `chain` object from the `functools`.

Comment: What's the better way to do it? I want to combine the results of different model query and then do my 'IF' thing

Comment: `type` does not return a string, it returns the class of the object passed to it...

Comment: So how will write the 'IF' statement considering that ```print(type(list(query)[0]))``` returns ```<class 'src.link.models.Fblink'>```

Comment: @Sammy: `isinstance(list(query)[0], Fblink)`

Comment: @Sammy: but it is quite bad design to do that. In fact using an `isinstance` is typically not a good idea, since it violates the open-close principle. Typically certain behavior is added to a common interface, and then implemented different in the subclasses.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem  It worked. Thanks a lot. But is there an alternative since you said that the solution is not recommended